# Conditionally assigning positional parameters in array in for loop in Bash?

Tags: arrays, bash, variables, for-loop, parameters

I have a script that I'll be using in a system where the first three positional parameters are reserved, but I want to pass other parameters to the script to be used as variables.  I can set default values for the variables, but if a parameter is included, I want that to take precedence.  Here's a very basic script to illustrate:

```
#!/bin/bash

param1="$1"
param2="$2"
param3="$3"
param4="default4"

if [[ "$param4" == "" ]] && [[ "$4" == "" ]]; then
    echo "A value was not specified for parameter 4. Script cannot execute. Exiting..."
    exit 1
elif [[ "$4" != "" ]]; then
    param4="$4"
else
    echo "The built-in value for parameter 4 will be used in the script."
fi

echo "$param1"
echo "$param2"
echo "$param3"
echo "$param4"
```

If I run `script a b c` the output I get is:

```
The built-in value for parameter 4 will be used in the script.
a
b
c
default4
```

If I run `script a b c d` then the output is:

```
a
b
c
d
```

This is all well and good, but if I have 5-6 different parameters, I don't want to have to repeat the `if..fi` block that many times for each parameter.

So I've been trying to use a for loop to iterate through the parameters, but I haven't had much luck.  The best attempt I came up with was:

```
#!/bin/bash

param1="$1"
param2="$2"
param3="$3"
param4="default4"
param5="default5"
param6="default6"
param7="default7"

defaultArray=( param4 param5 param6 param7 )
passedArray=( '$4' '$5' '$6' '$7' )

for (( i=0; i<${#defaultArray[@]}; i++ ));
do

    if [[ "${defaultArray[$i]}" == "" ]] && [[ "${passedArray[$i]}" == "" ]]; then
        echo "A value was not specified for parameter $((i+4)). Script cannot execute. Exiting..."
        exit 1
    elif [[ "${passedArray[$i]}" != "" ]]; then
        eval "${defaultArray[$i]}"='"${passedArray[$i]}"'
    else
        echo "The built-in value for parameter $((i+4)) will be used in the script."
    fi

done

echo "$param1"
echo "$param2"
echo "$param3"
echo "$param4"
echo "$param5"
echo "$param6"
echo "$param7"
```

But when I run this `script a b c`, or `script a b c d`, and whether or not I delete the default values in the script, I always get:

```
a
b
c
$4
$5
$6
$7
```

I think this because I needed to single-quote the positional parameter names in passedArray or else they just blank out, but then that hard-codes their names rather than the passed value.

Is there a way of doing this, or does trying to assign a positional parameter to a variable in an array and/or a for loop just not work?  The thing I'm going to try next is a function, but I'm not sure that'd work any better...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

```
param4="default4"

if [[ "$param4" == "" ]] && [[ "$4" == "" ]]; then
    echo "A value was not specified for parameter 4. Script cannot execute. Exiting..."
    exit 1
elif [[ "$4" != "" ]]; then
    param4="$4"
else
    echo "The built-in value for parameter 4 will be used in the script."
fi
```

To:

```
if [[ ! -z $4 ]]; then
  param4="$4"
else
  param4="default4"
  echo "The built-in value for parameter 4 will be used in the script."
fi
```

In your version of code, the first part of the `if` condition would never execute because param4 is already set just before `if`.

A more elegant and consiste way of doing this, given that you are using a default value for param4 anyway is:

```
param4=${4:-default4} # use default as "default4" unless $4 is set
```

For the second problem, your suspicion is right - single quotes won't expand the positional variables in the array assignment. So, change it to:

```
passedArray=( "$4" "$5" "$6" "$7" )
```

Your loops seems OK, except for this:

```
elif [[ "${passedArray[$i]}" != "" ]]; then
    eval "${defaultArray[$i]}"='"${passedArray[$i]}"'
```

Why use `eval` here?  You can say:

```
defaultArray[$i]=${passedArray[$i]}
```

Comment: `param4="${4-default4}"` instead will work if a blank value for `$4` is allowed. http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sh.html#uh-36 (and the sections before) is highly recommended reading for anyone shell scripting... (Especially if you deal with environments where /bin/sh might not be bash)

Comment: Thanks for the quick response @codeforester, and catching first check in the `if` never executing.  That's just a safeguard in case the script gets reused and a default value isn't set.  But I really like the  `param4=${4:-default4}` format.  I use `"${var:?}"` with `rm` so I don't accidentally delete an entire drive, but I had forgotten about the default substitution.  Double-quoting the passedArray worked too.  I guess when I was testing that before I wasn't passing enough parameters, which made those param4 and higher variables blank.

Comment: Thanks @GertvandenBerg, just picking up bash and shell scripting in general, always looking for great documentation!

Comment: @codeforester, the `eval` was when I was single-quoting the passedArray and getting the literal $4, $5, etc., in my results instead of the parameters, so I was trying `eval` to see if I could get it assign the passed parameter to the variable rather than the variable name, or number in this case...  Oh, and at first I thought the `param4="${4-default4}"` construct would just eliminate my first `if` check, but actually it completely eliminates the entire `if` statement and the array and everything.  This is for an OS X/macOS environment, so /bin/sh is bash, @GertvandenBerg.  :-)

Comment: Before reading the above posts that solved my problem, I decided to take another crack at this, still with the original defaultArray in a `for` loop rather than a function, but this time dropping passedArray.  I figured I could just compare and assign the positional parameters directly to the variables by using `defaultArray[$i]=${[$i]}`, though technically since the i started at 0, I triedto use `${[$((i+4))]}` to get the numbering to match $4, $5, etc.  But I kept getting bad substitution errors, trying to assign the parameters to the variables.  It's moot now, but curious why.

Comment: By the way, while `[[ ! -z $4 ]]` will work, it could be more easily written as simply [[ $4 ]], which is equivalent to [[ -n $4 ]], and returns 0 if the argument is not a null string, and 1 otherwise.

Comment: @pcrandom: `$2` is the name of a parameter. `$` is not an operator which takes a numeric argument. (In awk, it is. But this is shell.) The 2 looks like a number, but it is just a name. If you want to index arguments with a numeric expression, and you are using bash, use an argument slice `${@:start:length}`.